# Error if I choose not to fill a field value or Option Set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

ey guys,

So basically I have couple of option sets from where I choose a value and based on those value I calculate the result. 
I have 7 option sets, but it is not necessary that all 7 are used. SO if someone only chooses to use values from 3 of the option sets and leave the rest empty, the user gets the following error.

**There was an error in the field customized event.
Event: onSave
Error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference.**

now I realize that this error means that the other option set values are empty but how do I get past this?

I am using javascript to use the value from option set to multiply to a value in text field and get my result. Here is my code

```
function cashTotal()
{


if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1) 
{
var bill1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbills1").getSelectedOption().value;
var bill1Text = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbill1_text").getValue();

var result1 = bill1 * bill1Text;
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_total1").setValue(result1);


var bill2 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbills2").getSelectedOption().value;
var bill2Text = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbill2_text").getValue();

var result2 = bill2 * bill2Text;
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_total2").setValue(result2);


 var bill5 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbillls5").getSelectedOption().value;
var bill5Text = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbill5_text").getValue();

var result5 = bill5 * bill5Text;
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_total5").setValue(result5);



 var bill10 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbills10").getSelectedOption().value;
var bill10Text = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbill10_text").getValue();

var result10 = bill10 * bill10Text;
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_total10").setValue(result10);


  var bill20 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbills20").getSelectedOption().value;
var bill20Text = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbill20_text").getValue();

var result20 = bill20 * bill20Text;
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_total20").setValue(result20);





 var tmp = result1 + result2 + result5 + result10 + result20;

 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashtotal").setValue(tmp);

}
```

Comment: Basically `inmate_cashbills1` is the value from option set.
`inmate_cashbill1_text`  is a value that is multiplied by the option set value to give a result.

Comment: hos is that supposed to help? @Bizzon

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Instead of 
`var bill1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbills1").getSelectedOption().value;`

**DO**

`var bill1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbills1").getValue();`

Comment: If you need to retrieve the label you can go with:  `var bill1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_cashbills1").getText();`